# A word that means "bathroom singer"

Tags: single-word-requests

Actually, I don't like to put **bathroom** before **singer** as my hobby.

For example,  there's *decapitation* which exists for *beheaded*.

How do I replace the **bathroom singer** with an exact same meaning word?

Comment: Maybe just a "soloist"

Comment: :) Because the word decapitation means beheaded and it exists, ergo *bathroom singer* "must" also have a single word equivalent. That's the sum of your research?

Comment: What you likely need is a word replacing _bathroom_ in _bathroom singer_ (or a phrase/word replacing _bathroom singer_). I suggest you edit the question accordingly (add phrase-requests tag if you like it). I guess your best bet is _**amateur** singer_ because yourdictionary.com defines [bathroom-singer](http://www.yourdictionary.com/bathroom-singer) as "**a person with** mediocre or **amateur singing capabilities**"

Comment: To get more useful replies, try explaining exactly what you're trying to communicate by 'bathroom singer'. For example, say that you're actually able to sing but shy, or that you're not a professional singer, etc. Otherwise, all we have to go on is the location of your performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the definition is:

---

> **bathroom singer (Noun):**
>
> a person with mediocre or amateur singing capabilities.

---

So, you can infer that some synonyms of "Bathroom Singer" is:

- A bad singer
- Tone deaf
- etc.

You get the idea.

I hope this is helpful!